# Is it possible to create a LaTex table from R train() output?

Tags: tables

I am a newbie to LaTex and would like to create a table from a model of class train() from R. I have tried to find packages that will do this (xtable, stargazer) but haven't been able to find anything. Specifically, my models use a) cross-validated elastic net regression (from which I need the coefficients) and b) cross-validated regression (from which I need the coefficients, standard error, and p-values).

Am I missing something? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I guess that the easiest way would be using `knitr` or `longtable` with outputting your train set data to .csv file and reading it with `datatool` or `csvsimple`; but take it only from another newbie ;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggest you search this site for questions tagged with knitr. You will find examples that show how to generate tex using xtable, kable and stargazer. Otherwise post a minimal example showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Post at least the R code to produce that models from some R example database o some self-generated fake data. Take in mind that this is not an R site.